# Unable to register Outlook Add-in no matter what

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2016, addin-express

I've been developing an Outlook Add-in, been working and installing fine.
Then I tried to installed a really old version of the same add-in (trying to verify some old behaviour, the old plugin was for Outlook 2010), and it somehow messed up the install/uninstall process. Ever since then Office Outlook 2016/365 is not able to register/view the Add-in anymore.

I've tried the following:

- Uninstall and Reinstall Outlook
- Removes all the registry entries related to the Add-in (I literally search with the Add-in's keyword and removed hundreds of left over entries which I wasn't even aware of)
- Deleted c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office
- Deleted c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office
- Deleted c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\MyAddIn
- Ran CCleaner
- Ran RegDllView to scan all the registered DLLs, and it says **C:\WINDOWS\system32\mscoree.dll** is "missing"? But is there...
- Tried to uninstall and reinstall Add-in Express before recompile the whole project.

If i try to manually add the Add-in in Microsoft Outlook, Options > Add-ins > Manage > Add, if i point it to **MyAddIn.dll** it would say that it is not a valid COM Add-in (but nothing was changed in the project on how the dll was built). If i point it to **adxloader.dll** and hit OK, it won't complaint but nothing shows under Add-in either.

My next option is to completely reinstall Windows, this is driving me insane. Can anyone who have experienced this insanity give me some pointers?

Operating System: Windows 10

Office: Office 365 Outlook

Comment: Can you please share the log file ?

Comment: Hi @KhawajaAsim, what log file are you referring to? I don't think there is an Outlook startup log? I've uninstall and reinstall Office, reinstalled my plugin, but Outlook still won't load the plugin despite showing it under the Plugins tab.

Comment: Hi, there will be two log file names like adxloader.log and adxregistrator.log in Documents/Add-in Express folder.